# Embedded document's fields are always NULL

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm

here is a document example:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("52ae09f8211b6f57548b4568"),
    "active" : 1,
    "author" : "582127753",
    "contact" : "ntrms-4148701995@domain.com",
    "coordinates" : {
            "lat" : 35.691048,
            "lng" : 139.701065
    },
    "date" : ISODate("2013-10-24T18:41:42Z")
```

Now when I run the query to get this document I have an answer like this

```
  array(2) {
  ["52ae09f8211b6f57548b4568"]=>
  object(ng\NearBundle\Document\Markers)#213 (14) {
    ["id":protected]=>
    string(24) "52ae09f8211b6f57548b4568"
    ["coordinates":protected]=>
    object(ng\NearBundle\Document\Coordinates)#216 (2) {
      ["lat":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["lng":protected]=>
      NULL
    }
```

The coordinate document:

```
<?php
namespace ng\NearBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/** @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument */
class Coordinates
{
    /** @MongoDB\Float */
    protected $lat;

    /** @MongoDB\Float */
    protected $lng;

    public function __construct($lat = 0.0, $lng = 0.0)
    {
        $this->setLat($lat);
        $this->setLng($lng);
    }

    /**
     * Set lat
     *
     * @param float $lat
     * @return \Coordinates
     */
    public function setLat($lat)
    {
        $this->lat = $lat;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lat
     *
     * @return float $lat
     */
    public function getLat()
    {
        return $this->lat;
    }

    /**
     * Set lng
     *
     * @param float $lng
     * @return \Coordinates
     */
    public function setLng($lng)
    {
        $this->lng = $lng;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lng
     *
     * @return float $lng
     */
    public function getLng()
    {
        return $this->lng;
    }
}
```

and in the Initial document where it's referenced :

```
/** @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Coordinates") */
    protected $coordinates;
```

Can anyone tells me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem with the following test case:

```
namespace Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Tests;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

class SO21091204Test extends BaseTest
{
    public function test1()
    {
        $coordinates = new TestCoordinates();
        $coordinates->lat = 1.2;
        $coordinates->lng = 3.4;

        $document = new TestDocument();
        $document->coordinates = $coordinates;

        $this->dm->persist($document);
        $this->dm->flush();
        $this->dm->clear();

        $document = $this->dm->find(get_class($document), $document->id);

        $this->assertSame(1.2, $document->coordinates->lat);
        $this->assertSame(3.4, $document->coordinates->lng);
    }
}

/** @ODM\Document */
class TestDocument
{
    /** @ODM\Id */
    public $id;

    /** @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="TestCoordinates") */
    public $coordinates;
}

/** @ODM\EmbeddedDocument */
class TestCoordinates
{
    /** @ODM\Float */
    public $lat;

    /** @ODM\Float */
    public $lng;
}
```

Since your document example was likely from a the MongoDB shell (it looks like JSON), you may want to issue a non-hydrated query through ODM to see the raw value in PHP. This would at least show you the data that ODM is receiving:

```
$rs = $dm->createQueryBuilder('ng\NearBundle\Document\Markers')
    ->field('id')->equals('52ae09f8211b6f57548b4568')
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();

var_dump($rs);
```